# What are the equations for the different Sprite Kit SKBlendMode options?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, blending

**Sprite Kit SKBlendMode FAQ**

For each of the Sprite Kit `SKBlendMode` options:

- SKBlendModeAlpha
- SKBlendModeAdd
- SKBlendModeSubtract
- SKBlendModeMultiply
- SKBlendModeMultiplyX2
- SKBlendModeScreen
- SKBlendModeReplace

1. What are the equations governing the blending?
2. Is there an equivalent OpenGL blending mode (e.g. using `glBlendFunc`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SKBlendModeAlpha**

```
// Equations
output.r = src.r * src.alpha + dst.r * (1 - src.alpha);
output.g = src.g * src.alpha + dst.g * (1 - src.alpha);
output.b = src.b * src.alpha + dst.b * (1 - src.alpha);
output.a = src.a * src.alpha + dst.a * (1 - src.alpha);

// OpenGL Equivalent
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```